# Append to clojure vector from within loop

Tags: clojure

I have:

```
(defn keep?

   (def sum [])
     (loop [i 0]
        (when (< i 10)
           (conj sum 10)
           (recur (inc i))))
     sum
   )
```

This just gives me and empty vector even though I am conj-ing 10 onto sum. Is this because it is not in-scope within the Loop? How would I achieve the same outcome. (btw, this example is deliberately simplified)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conj` does not modify its argument. In fact, without resorting to evil reflection tricks, nothing will modify a vector, it's an immutable data structure. This is one of the fundamental principles of Clojure.

In functional programming, instead of modifying data, we replace it with another immutable value. So you need to use the return value of `conj`, or it is effectively a noop.

```
(defn keep?
  []
  (loop [i 0 sum []]
    (if (< i 10)
      (recur (inc i) (conj sum 10))
      sum)))
```

Also, the second arg to `defn` must always be a vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is just what I needed. I did know this, but it is surprising how easily one slips back into imperative mutability land....

Answer (score 4):

`conj` is not destructive, it does not alter that collection, returns a new collection with the designated state ([reference](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj)).

To achieve the desired result, you may:

- Define `sum` in a `loop`-form, like `i` is defined, instead of using `def`
- `recur (inc i) (conj sum 10)` to rebind `sum` to a new one on every iteration, so that state is built up to what you expect
- Once the condition in `when` is not met, just return `sum` from your `loop` and it will bubble up to become the return value of this function. Uh hang on, `when` does not have an "else-branch", a possible alternative is `if`

Like so:

```
(defn keep? []
     (loop [i   0
            sum []]
           (if (< i 10)
               (recur (inc i)
                      (conj sum 10))
               sum)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement the other answers, I almost never use the `loop` function.  Here are a few ways to do it using the `for` function:

```
; return a lazy sequence
(for [i (range 10) ]
  i)
;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

; return a concrete vector
(vec
  (for [i (range 10) ]
    i))
;=> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

; 'into' is very nice for converting one collection into another
(into #{}
  (for [i (range 10) ]
    i))
;=> #{0 7 1 4 6 3 2 9 5 8}   ; hash-set is unique but unordered
```